# HTML Parsing and Mapping

Tags: java, javascript, html

I intend to build some translation-like web application where a user viewing a html page (which I had collected from the web and stored offline on the server side) and then the user will need to interact with the text inside this html, by selecting some subset of the characters (asking for translation-like operation)..

so the process here is divided to 3 parts:

- Extract the plain text from the html file

- The plain text will be pre-processed on the server and stored offline

- When the user selects a string online in the html, I need to identify the mapping in the plain text I had already extracted and stored offline.

For the plain-text-extraction I use jsoup.

 and I had already pre-processed the plain files..

any ideas about the mapping part and identifying what text the user selected (or clicked)?

[Working on Java, Apache-Tomcat, JavaScript, linux ]

Comment: You want to map what? HTML<>text, text<>translation, HTML<>translation, selected HTML<>selected text, ...?